# Convert Jython to Java

Tags: java, jython-2.5

How can I convert the code below from Jython to Java?

The code will be used to run the Junit test to set the proxy details to make JUnits more usable.

Jyhon code:

```
from java.lang import *;
from com.parasoft.preferences import *;
from com.parasoft.proxy import *;

def SetupProxy(item, context):
    preferences = AppPreferenceProvider.getProxyPreferenceProvider();
    preferences.setProxyConfiguration("bisn.parasoft.com", "3128", "", "", "", "")
    preferences.setUseProxy(1)
    preferences.setUseProxyAutoConfig(0);
    preferences.setUseSameProxySettings(1)
    preferences.setUseProxyAuthentication(1)
    preferences.setProxyUserId("devtest")
    preferences.setProxyPasswd("dev%pass")
    preferences.setSystemProxy(Boolean(0));
```

Comment: I just submitted an edit to your question in which I removed the JavaScript tag and replaced it with the Java tag, since this is what you mention in your title and question (Java and JavaScript are **not** the same thing). If this is not want you intended then please feel free to change the tags back. Welcome to SO!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question--it almost *is* Java; what doesn't work? How is it related to XML?

Comment: @DaveNewton Jython follows python syntax.

Comment: @thavan Yes, I know. And the sample provided is almost translatable verbatim to Java.

Comment: Thanks Chris and Dave your understanding is correct this is Jython code ... and we need to convert into java code to fix your proxy related issue. I tried this code but didn't work at my end can anyone fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since `jython` compiles into a `.jar`, there is no reason to convert the source code into java. However, if you really need to this, it is almost straightforward:

1. Add the `package ....` line to the top
2. Change all `from a import b` into `import a.b` (in your case, `b` is `*`, though you should avoid that)
3. The function must be inside a `class` and probably static. You could for example call the class `SetupProxy`, too.
4. The variables (`item`, `context` and `preferences`) must have a type declaration.

Of course, you can also decompile the `.jar` generated via `jython` to get some inspiration...